# Contraint Constant = <= >= XIB Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Estoy interesado en saber exactamente como funciona en el diseñador de pantallas de Xcode las opciones de "=" || ">=" || "<=" por lo que aun no las entiendo corectamente estas opciones son estas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que parece que probandolas es que como maximo puede ponerle 5 de margen si el tamaño es pequenño sino le pone mas pero si o si es 5 lo minimo, aunque nose si se puede sacar mas provecho a estas funcionalidades, veo que si a un bottom le agrego >=, ya con los demas me da conflicto si quiero poner la misma restriccion y siento que no lo comprendo bien

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente los operadores `≤` y `≥` permiten ajustar una *constraint* para que tenga un valor máximo o mínimo respectivamente. Sin embargo, estas restricciones tienen más sentido cuando se usan junto con prioridades (`Priority`).
El motivo es que, durante la ejecución, el tamaño de la pantalla podría no satisfacer las restricciones o algunas de ellas podrían entrar en conflicto entre sí. Asignando prioridades, ante un conflicto de restricciones, se tomará en cuenta la restricción con la prioridad más baja.
Es probable que en tu botón haya varias restricciones en conflicto, por lo que te aconsejo probar a cambiar la prioridad para ver si el conflicto desaparece.

En [Auto Layout Guide: Working with Constraints in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1) puedes encontrar más información acerca de como trabajar con constraints en Interface Builder.